# Pattern for multithread callers / worker

Tags: c, multithreading, design-patterns, pthreads

I am looking for a good design patter for my multithreaded c application.

My problem is :

1. I have a number of "caller" threads that are calling some functions.
2. Those functions should be executed by one single other "worker" thread
3. During the time the worker is idle in executing, the callers are waiting for the result of the requested operation.

My idea is to separate the responsibility of calling a certain set of functions to this worker thread.

First then code blindly a bunch of mutex and events, the question in my mind is.. Witch pattern should I use ? Do you have any advise for me ? Being new to threads in c, both design and technical ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your worker is an [active object](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/prefer-using-active-objects-instead-of-n/225700095) (albeit with blocking rather than async calls).

Comment: I think you are right! http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's called the [Thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). Your "callers" enqueue tasks to a single queue, and all workers wait on that queue.

Comment: The idea is to have only one worker and give to him all the tasks. And the callers should wait for the task execution end. Do you think that Thread Pool can fit my problem or I have a too specific case ?

Comment: So you want to serialize access to a resource. More appropriate is to have a mutex protecting that resource.